# LibGDX camera rotation does not work on Android

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, orientation, android-sensors

I have the orientation values from Android device **RotationVector sensor** expressed in degress as Yaw, Pitch and Roll angles. I want to **continuously update** the LibGDX Perspective camera rotation based on these orientation values. My goal is to build a **3D compass**.

In the render() method I am trying:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK, true);

    // do some rendering
    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance, lights);
    modelBatch.end();
    
    // calculate/get the orientation angles
    float Yaw = ...;
    float Pitch = ...;
    float Roll = ...;

    // update camera orientation
    cam.view.setFromEulerAngles(Yaw, Pitch, Roll);
    cam.update();
}
```

I see the continuously changing Yaw/Pitch/Roll values in the logcat on the Android device orientation change, but unfortunately my model (the 3D compass) does not rotate. What is wrong with the above code? Why the camera rotation does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bornander I ended up with the below perfectly working code:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    // clear screen
    ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK, true);
    
    // do some rendering
    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance, lights);
    modelBatch.end();

    // calculate Azimuth (Yaw), Pitch and Roll angles (in degress)
    float Azimuth = ...
    float Pitch = ...
    float Roll = ...

    // Transform the Forward vector (Vector3.Z) using a quaternion got from Azimuth/Pitch angles to a LookAt vector
    Quaternion rotCam = new Quaternion().setEulerAngles(Azimuth, Pitch, 0);
    Vector3 newDir = new Vector3(Vector3.Z).mul(rotCam).nor();
    cam.lookAt(newDir);

    // Transform the camera UP vector (Vector3.Y) using a quaternion got from previous LookAt vector and Roll angle
    Quaternion rotUp = new Quaternion(newDir, Roll);
    Vector3 newUp = new Vector3(Vector3.Y).mul(rotUp).nor();
    cam.up.set(newUp);

    // apply the above changes on camera
    cam.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you cannot update the `view` of a `PerspectiveCamera` directly as it will be overwritten by the call to `update`.

You control a `PerspectiveCamera` by modifying the `position` and the `direction` (or look-at target).

You need to calculate a new direction based on your roll, yaw and pitch and then set that on the `camera`.

For reference, this is the implementation of `update` in `PerspectiveCamera`:

```
public void update(boolean updateFrustum) {
    float aspect = this.viewportWidth / this.viewportHeight;
    this.projection.setToProjection(Math.abs(this.near), Math.abs(this.far), this.fieldOfView, aspect);
    this.view.setToLookAt(this.position, this.tmp.set(this.position).add(this.direction), this.up);
    this.combined.set(this.projection);
    Matrix4.mul(this.combined.val, this.view.val);
    if (updateFrustum) {
        this.invProjectionView.set(this.combined);
        Matrix4.inv(this.invProjectionView.val);
        this.frustum.update(this.invProjectionView);
    }

}
```

Notice that is overwrites `view`.

This answer only applies if you are indeed using a `PerspectiveCamera`.

One way of using *yaw*, *pitch* and *roll* with a `PerspectiveCamera` could be to transform a *forward* vector using the matrix you already calculate using `setFromEulerAngles`, for example:

```
    Vector3 forward = new Vector3(Vector3.Z);
    Matrix4 mat = new Matrix4();
    mat.idt().setFromEulerAngles(yaw, pitch, roll);
    forward.mul(mat);

    Vector3 lookAtTarget = new Vector3();
    lookAtTarget.set(camera.position).add(forward);

    camera.lookAt(lookAtTarget);
    camera.update();
```

Comment: "You need to calculate a new direction based on your roll, yaw and pitch and then set that on the camera."
Do you know, how to do that in LibGDX ?

Comment: I'll update my answer to include something for this as well, @Ladislav.

Comment: Thanks! By just reading your sample code it makes absolutely sense! I'll definitely try that. Anyway, I really miss something like that as a builtin "utility" function in LibGDX.

Comment: Interesting, that however now it works, but the Roll angles are somehow "not processed", means when the Android device's screen is facing to me and I tilt it left or right, nothing happens. In other words the rotation around Z axis is somehow does not work.

Comment: That is a different question, that is an Android sensor-question rather than a libGDX camera-question.

Comment: I don't think so. Problem is definitely at the LibGDX camera lookAt setting, because if I check the Yaw, Pitch, Roll values in Android logcat, they are always correct and follow the device orientation. Means when I hold the device with screen facing to me and rotate around the Y-axis (the vertical axis, pointing to the sky), only the Yaw values are changing. When I rotate around X-axis (the horizontal axis, tilting the device), only the Pitch values are changing. Finally when I rotate around Z-axis, only the Roll values are changing (in the logcat output only, sadly).

Comment: I have a feeling that it is not possible to rotate the camera around axis-Z in LibGDX. At least not via its lookAt( ) method. My goal is to rotate also the camera itself around its DIRECTION axis.

Comment: You need to set the cameras Up-vector to match the roll.

Comment: OK, this is a new info for me :) I'll definitely try that. Thanks for hint!